# Как реализовать удалённое управление?

Tags: java

Добрый день, есть программам с файлом конфигурации предполагаться её использовать на большом количестве машин, но если меняется конфигурация то нужно будет обходить все машины и менять её на каждой. Я вижу выход в том что бы написать ещё одну программу с помощью которой можно менять конфигурацию на всех остальных машинах, посоветуйте как правильно можно это реализовать ?

Comment: Вы уверены что стоит писать свой велосипед? судя по вашей задаче, с ней бы справился ansible

Comment: @ArtemKonovalov может быть, но есть желание написать велосипед.

Comment: какая ос на тачках?

Comment: @ArtemKonovalov windows

Comment: Создать на сервере для каждой машины каталог с конфигурацией и с помощью robocopy копировать каждый на сою машину

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Есть несколько вариантов, как это реализовать:

- Распределенное приложение, где будут некоторые агенты, находящиеся на удаленных машинах и случающие определенный порт, и управляющее приложение, которое бы отправляло команды этим агентам. В качестве коммуникации можно использовать либо обычный `rest`, либо `rmi` либо что нибудь в этом духе.
- Написать одно приложение, которое бы подключалось к удаленным машинам используя стандартные средства ос. В `linux`, это реализовывалось бы через команду `ssh`, возможно в `windows` тоже есть какие то аналоги этого
- Сделать механизм централизованного хранения конфигурации, откуда бы бралась информация перед каждым запуском приложения.

Comment: Как Вы думаете если написать web форму забивать конфиги в неё а программа при запуске брала всё что нужно из неё ?

Comment: @VargSieg А конфиги из вебформы куда бы отправлялись?

Comment: На машины пользователей.

Comment: Ну собственно, это первый вариант из моего ответа